# Add a text near my checkbox slider

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm using some slider to replace my checkboxes.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="switch small">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider small"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dky16b53/

How can I add some text near each sliders please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a quick hack for it. Add a `<span>` for each side text and put `position: absolute` and `margin` on it.

**EDIT: Now with check/uncheck functionality**:

https://jsfiddle.net/dky16b53/2/

HTML:

```
<label class="switch small">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="slider small"></div>
</label>
<span>More Text</span>
```

CSS:

```
..existing code 

div span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @Terry just cuz I don't know why `position: absolute` vertically centers the span lol

Comment: Problem is I lost the <label> click functionality to check/uncheck.

Comment: @user8201518 Interesting. In my JSFiddle it works fine.

Comment: I mean click on the text to check/uncheck.

Comment: @user8201518 I did it, but with jQuery. With JS, i have no idea. Check my new JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Put some text after the label tag, but still in the div.col-sm-4. See the span element below.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="switch small">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider small"></div>
    </label>
    <span>Text next to slider</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Alignment is off. You'll need some CSS.

Comment: And like the other example, the problem is I lost the click functionality to check/uncheck.